Using PowerShell and MSGraphAPI, how can I get the user GUID from an email address to write to a Person Or Group field?
I am using PowerShell and MSGraphAPI to write to SharePoint.  I am pulling the user principal name like this:
$AssignedTech = (Get-ADUser $ENV:UserName -Properties userPrincipalName -Server ServerName.mycompany.local | Select UserPrincipalName).UserPrincipalName

This is successfully grabbing the users email address, however when I write to a new entry, all properties are written except for this field.  I know I need to somehow lookup the user's ObjectID but I can't figure out how to do that.
My code that is writing to SharePoint is as follows.
$params = @{
            fields = @{
                "Title"                            = "$DecomServer";
                "IP_x0020_Address"                 = "$IP";
                "Assigned_x0020_Application"       = "$Application";
                "Domain"                           = "$Domain";
                "Machine_x0020_Type"               = "$MachineType";
                "Change_x0020_Ticket_x0020_Number" = "$ChangeControl";
                "Assigned_x0020_Tech"              = "$AssignedTech";
                "OSVersion"                        = "$OS";
                "DateTurnedOff"                    = Get-Date;
                "RemoveDate"                       = (Get-Date).AddDays(60)
                }
        }
        New-MgSiteListItem -SiteId $siteId -ListId $listId -BodyParameter $params

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to convert the UserprincipalName to the ObjectID needed for a Person or Group field?

Are you just looking for something like  get-aduser -Filter { (UserPrincipalName -eq $assignedtech) } -properties * | select ObjectGuid ?

After working with Microsoft I was able to come up with this sample code to populate the People/Group property.  The key was learning that you need to add "LookupId" to the end of the property name.

#********************************************************************************************************
#********************************************************************************************************
#               Sample to Populate a People/Group Property
#
#               Note that the property name is Assigned_x0020_Tech but you must
#               append "LookupId" (case sensitive) to the name. Also note that you must query the 
#               user to get their LookupID to pass to the property. This pulls from a list of site users.         
#********************************************************************************************************
#********************************************************************************************************
$AssignedTech = (Get-ADUser $ENV:UserName -Server $ADSyncServer).UserPrincipalName
$AssignedTechID = ((Get-PnPUser -WithRightsAssigned | Select-Object *| where-object {$_.Email -eq $AssignedTech}).ID)

$params = @{
    fields = @{
        "Title"                            = "$DecomServer";
        "IP_x0020_Address"                 = "$IP";
        "Assigned_x0020_Application"       = "$Application";
        "Domain"                           = "$Domain";
        "Machine_x0020_Type"               = "$MachineType";
        "Change_x0020_Ticket_x0020_Number" = "$ChangeControl";
        "Assigned_x0020_TechLookupId"      = "$AssignedTechID";
        "OSVersion"                        = "$OS";
        "DateTurnedOff"                    = Get-Date;
        "RemoveDate"                       = (Get-Date).AddDays(60)
    }
}
New-MgSiteListItem -SiteId $siteId -ListId $listId -BodyParameter $params 

